# Booolean Default Value

Tags: solidity, function

In a tutorial I have written the below code

In this instance it would now throw a exception with the user feedback that the transaction did not go through. I don't know how the bool works in this situation? Are bools not defaulted to false and thus we are requiring the function to be false?

```
        bool isSent = _toWhom.send(10);
        require (isSent, "Sending funds unsuccessfull");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
   bool isSent = payable(receiver).send(10);
   require (isSent, "Sending funds unsuccessfull");
```

so maybe try adding the explicite 'payable' keyword?

But you are right that 'send' gives back a bool for success and your require should work on success of the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

For sending ether your contract needs to own enough ether first. `_toWhom.send` sends ether from the contract to `_toWhom`.